# Typescript: this.http.get does not call my web API method

Tags: angular, typescript, asp.net-core-webapi

The following URL works - I've tested it in Chrome and Postman.

```
https://localhost:44319/api/portfolio
```

Here is my invocation in my typescript module. I have a breakpoint on this line and I see this line execute. (If you think a broader view of my code is relevant to the question, please let me know and I will post it.)

```
this.http.get<Portfolio[]>('https://localhost:44319/api/portfolio');
```

The line executes, but my web API method doesn't get called. I know it's not getting called because I am running my project in debug mode and I have breakpoints in my typescript method and in the first line of my web API method. I see the breakpoint being hit within the typescript executing on the client side, but the breakpoint within my server side web API method doesn't get hit.

(Although, as I mentioned, if I execute that exact URL from Chrome or Postman the server-side breakpoint hits.)

What am I doing wrong? Thanks!

Comment: How does the scoring work? Three people marked the answer to this question as useful but overall this gets marked as -1?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should do:

```
this.http.get<Portfolio[]>('https://localhost:44319/api/portfolio').subscribe(v
 => { this.Portfolios = r; });
```

or

```
this.Portfolios = await this.http.get<Portfolio[]>('https://localhost:44319/api/portfolio').toPromise();
```

Comment: Thanks! How do I assign the functional return of that API call to the array of Portfolio objects? Defined a a class member variable: public Portfolios: Portfolio[] ;

Comment: this.Portfolios[] = await this.http.get('https://localhost:44319/api/portfolio').toPromise(); This doesn't work for me I get an error becasue it doesn;t want to assign an 'object' to my array of Portfolios. Thanks!

Comment: just remove the brackets

Comment: When I change this to this.Portfolios = await this.http.get('https://localhost:44319/api/portfolio').toPromise(); I get the following syntax error: The 'Object' type is assignable to very few other types. Did you mean to use the 'any' type instead? Type 'Object' is missing the following properties from type 'Portfolio[]': length, pop, push, concat and 26 more.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand. Can you show me? Thanks!

Comment: I've changed my answer. Is is still wrong? Do you get compile or runtime error?

Comment: Thanks! I got it!        this.http.get<Portfolio[]>('https://localhost:44319/api/portfolio').subscribe((portfolios: Portfolio[]): void =>
          {
          this.Portfolios = portfolios;
          }
        ); (Plus I need to initialize this.Portfolios on its declaration - public Portfolios: Portfolio[] = [] ; It's working now and I see all Portfolio entries in my HTML dropdown. Thanks!